# Sum of production of k out of n variables

Tags: combinatorics

Given a vector of positive values $$v_{1:n} = <v_1,v_2,,,,v_n>$$, define $$SumProd(v_{1:n},k) = \sum_{s \in S_k^n} \prod_{i \in s} v_i$$. It seems that this requires $O(n^k)$ computation. Is there a faster way to compute SumProd?

Comment: Use the recurrence $$\text{SumProd}(v_{1:n},k)=\text{SumProd}(v_{1:(n-1)},k)+v_{n}\cdot \text{SumProd}(v_{1:(n-1)},k-1)$$to compute this with dynamic programming in $O(nk)$ time.

Answer (score 1):

It is commonly denoted by $e_k(v_1,\ldots,v_n)$ and called the $k$-th elementary symmetric polynomial.

Using [Newton's identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_identities#Formulation_in_terms_of_symmetric_polynomials) (let's assume $e_0(v_1,\ldots,v_n):=1$ below) $$ke_k(v_1,\ldots,v_n)=\sum_{j=1}^{k}(-1)^{j-1}e_{k-j}(v_1,\ldots,v_n)p_j(v_1,\ldots,v_n),$$ where $p_j(v_1,\ldots,v_n):=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}v_i^j$, it is computed iteratively in $\mathcal{O}(nk)$ operations.